# Crossing number of 3-regular graphs

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

What's the largest possible crossing number for a $3$-regular graph? And what about the largest crossing number for a $3$-regular Hamiltonian graph?

Comment: Probably we are talking about graphs of a given order:
What's the largest possible crossing number for a 3-regular graph of order $n$? Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you can extract [from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_number_(graph_theory)#Cubic_graphs) for cubic graphs of small orders:
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
{\rm Number\ of\ vertices} & {\rm Largest\ crossing\ number} \\
\hline
2,4 & 0 \\
6,8 & 1 \\
10,12 & 2 \\
14 & 3\\
16 & 4\\
18 & 5\\
20 & 6\\
22 & 7\\
24 & 8\\
26 & [8,10]\\
28 & [11,13]\\
30 & \geq 13
\end{array}
$$
Some other [inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_number_inequality) on the number of crossings of a graph are known, which allow you to estimate your number as well. You can find a lot of literature on a topic close to you at these links.

I think your second question could be answered in about the same way. You just need to look carefully at the minimal examples - they all seem to be Hamiltonian.

I hope this answer helped you a little, though of course it looks more like a long comment.